# Chrome extension that automatically removes elements from history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with the chrome extension project I'm working on.
Generally, it has only one purpose -  to remove the addresses from browsing history that is included in the array. (later on, I'm going to add some UI for it ). The chrome background console doesn't show any errors - additionally, I did it just like the documentation said.
How to make that chrome extension background script removing array elements from history.

```js
console.log("hi");
// delete URL

const arr = [
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://www.messenger.com/",
    "https://www.netflix.com/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/"
]


arr.forEach( site => {
    console.log(site)
    chrome.history.deleteUrl({ url: site });
});
```

Comment: You have "history" in your manifest and after executing this you still see "https://www.youtube.com/" in chrome://history? Do you get your log as expected?

Comment: Yes, logs are just as expected and I still have in chrome://history all stuff that wasn't supposed to be there. Manifest includes permissions for history ( I think now Id wouldn't be able to start extension outherwise btw )

Comment: By stuff that is not supposed to be there you mean these 4 pages? Because it only delete exact matches, not all links for the domain

Comment: oh so how should i do it ? i want tto remove youtube.com/video1 as well as any item in history that includes "youtube.com" part

Comment: I can't think of any elegant solution, but you can go through the history and check each individual link, if it contains certain domain, delete it